# Facebook Omniauth login not returning all fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth

I'm setting up the Facebook provider as follows:

```
provider :facebook, ENV['FACEBOOK_APP_ID'], ENV['FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET'], scope: ['email', 'public_profile']
```

The authorization appears to work fine, in that the Facebook dialog mentions the relevant requested permissions, but I'm only getting name and picture details coming back to the callback URL. The `omniauth.auth` hash looks as follows:

`{
    "provider":"facebook",
    "uid":<redacted>
    "info":{
        "name":<redacted>,
        "image":<redacted>,
        "credentials":{
            "token":<redacted>,
            "expires_at":1442319308,
            "expires":true
        },
        "extra":{
            "raw_info":{
                "name":<redacted>,
                "id":<redacted>
            }
        }
    }`

Shouldn't I be seeing more fields here?

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same problem. You've probably figured this out, but in case you haven't... You just need to make sure to edit Devise.rb in addition to Omniauth.rb

Devise.rb should have:

```
config.omniauth :facebook, "your_facebook_id", "your_facebook_secret", scope: 'email,public_profile', info_fields: 'email, first_name, last_name'
```

replacing whatever specific info_fields you need (list of all available [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/))

Comment: Works for me, using Authlogic but the key is specifying the info_fields:  Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :facebook, MY_ID, MY_SECRET, scope: 'email,public_profile', info_fields: 'email,first_name,last_name'